# What is the plain R equivalent of an aggregation sqldf query?

Tags: r

What is the plain `R` equivalent command of the following `sqldf` query"

```
test <- sqldf("SELECT *, SUM(value) FROM dataFrame GROUP BY run")
```

I try something like:

```
test <-aggregate(dataFrame$value, by=list(dataFrame$run), FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

but somehow the `SUM` happens on each column of `dataFrame`

Comment: It's SO custom to "clean up"/delete comments after they are obsolete (having been integrated into the Q and/or A). You can see an (x) for that when hovering over your own comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, the `sqldf` commands get the `sum` of the 'value' column grouped by 'run' along with the last observation other columns (if any) for each 'run'.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT *, SUM(value) FROM dataFrame GROUP BY run")
#  run        value    value2 SUM(value)
#1   a -0.848370044 0.2387489 -0.1627249
#2   b  0.002311942 0.3688175 -0.6826107
#3   c -1.316908124        NA -0.3993579
```

To get similar output with `aggregate`, you may try two `aggregate`s.  First, to get the `sum` of the 'value' and second for the last observation per group.  If there are `NA` values, specify `na.rm=TRUE` argument of `sum` as well as the `na.action=NULL` from the `aggregate`.  The default option in `aggregate` is `na.action=na.omit`, which can remove a complete row from calculation if there is any 'NA' values.

```
d1 <- aggregate(value~run, dataFrame, FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE, na.action=NULL)
d2 <- aggregate(.~run, dataFrame, tail,1, na.action=NULL)
```

and `merge` by 'run'

```
merge(d1, d2, by='run')
#  run    value.x      value.y    value2
#1   a -0.1627249 -0.848370044 0.2387489
#2   b -0.6826107  0.002311942 0.3688175
#3   c -0.3993579 -1.316908124        NA
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dataFrame)[,c(.SD[.N], SUMVALUE=sum(value, na.rm=TRUE)) , run]
#   run        value    value2   SUMVALUE
#1:   a -0.848370044 0.2387489 -0.1627249
#2:   b  0.002311942 0.3688175 -0.6826107
#3:   c -1.316908124        NA -0.3993579
```

Or with `dplyr` (thanks for @Frank)

```
library(dplyr)
dataFrame %>%
    group_by(run) %>%
    mutate(SUMVALUE=sum(value,na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
    slice(n())
#  run        value    value2   SUMVALUE
#1   a -0.848370044 0.2387489 -0.1627249
#2   b  0.002311942 0.3688175 -0.6826107
#3   c -1.316908124        NA -0.3993579
```

#### data

```
  set.seed(24)
  dataFrame <- data.frame(run=rep(letters[1:3], 4), 
           value=c(NA,rnorm(11)), value2=c(runif(11), NA))
```

Comment: Found a not-too-bad `dplyr` way: `dataFrame %>% group_by(run) %>% mutate(s=sum(value,na.rm=TRUE)) %>% slice(n())` Unfortunately, it breaks if you have a data.table, thanks to this bug: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/919